# NGINX block location access and redirect to custom error page

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, blocking, custom-errors, error-handling

I have a issue with my NGINX setting with redirecting to a custom error page on another location (incl. css, images, js) if a error page should be thrown.

At first I would like to block access to an folder (like `.git`). This can be easily done via (inside the server block)

```
location ~ /(.git) {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}
```

Then i created a custom error_page element (inside the server block) with a custom 404.html file on a different location than the root directory of the website.

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root /var/data/websites/error-page;
    internal;
}
```

After these changes, my custom 404 page will be shown - but without css, js and images.

If i inspect the website, the reason is simple: the path of the files are wrong - they are based on the location (in my example `.git`).
`https://it.dmetzler1988.io/.git/css/main.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404`.

Here is the complete NGINX config file for this page (only removed the ssl certificate paths):

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate <path>;
    ssl_certificate_key <path>;

    server_name it.dmetzler1988.io;
    root /var/data/websites/dmetzler1988.io/it.dmetzler1988.io;
    index index.html index.php;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /var/data/websites/error-page;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ /(.git) {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }
}
```

So my questions on this place:

1. How can i fix the issue with the wrong path (remove the `.git` from path)?
2. Is this the correct way for such an use case or is there a better solution?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. It's best to keep the assets (main.css, main.js, etc) in a separate folder (such as in /example-folder/) and then use an additional location block (`location /example-folder/ { alias "/path/to/example-folder"; }`) with custom root or alias to serve those files.

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu Your solution requires an `alias /path/to/example-folder/` directive to work properly (note the trailing slash). Without it request like `/example-folder/css/main.css` would be served as `/path/to/example-foldercss/main.css` obviously giving you an `HTTP 404 Not Found` error. I described this `alias` behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69296739/7121513).

Comment: @IvanShatsky I tried it so than you described it (also tried various modifications) but it won't work for my css (used only css path for tests). `location ~* /.git/css/.* { root /var/data/websites/error-page/css; }`. Is there something wrong? I receive the 404 error for this file also after adding the new location.

Comment: @devKyrios Can you add config you tried as an update to your question?

Comment: @IvanShatsky haha, sorry, was to slow with editing. Is now added. I tried it with and without the `/.*` at the end. Also with case sensitive locations and so on.

Comment: @IvanShatsky oh damn.. sorry, nevermind - my fail. It doesn't work with the location block which i added yesterday ( `location ~ /\.git { return 404; }` ). I have a overlapping location block. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First, about the errors in your config.

```
location ~ /(.git) { ... }
```

Looks you are not quite familiar with PCRE regex patterns. There is no need to use a capture group here - capture groups are used when you'd need its content later. However it isn't a critical error. The worst part is that you use unshielded dot char, which work as wildcard in regex patterns. This way you effectively blocking any URI containing a string where second, third and fourth chars are `git` (e.g. `/agitation/index.html`, `/any/prefix/agitation/index.html`, etc.) The right regex pattern here will be `/\.git` (blocking anything starting with `.git` including `.gitignore`, etc. on any nested directory level).

Next, you are using two directives in that location - `deny all` and `return 404`. Only one of them will be sufficient here - either `deny all` (returning `HTTP 403 Forbidden`) or `return 404` (returning `HTTP 404 Not Found`). The reason you are getting 404 rather than 403 is that `return` directive executed at the `REWRITE` request processing phase while `deny` one executed at the later `ACCESS` phase (request processing phases described in the [development guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases)).

Now back to your question. Looks like you are referring your assets using relative URI paths, e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
```

Some of your options are (but not limited to):

- embed every asset into the error handler HTML (including your images, you can do it encoding your images to BASE64 and using the [Data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs));
- move all the assets to the some folder under your main site webroot (say `/var/data/websites/dmetzler1988.io/it.dmetzler1988.io/assets/errors` and refer them using the full path:

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/errors/css/main.css">
  ```

Comment: At first, thank you a lot for your useful feedback! My knowledge about regex in NGINX seems to be wrong. Also the directive information was very helpful - so i be safe with the `return 404` directive only.

Your both ideas to solve the sources issue would be a solution, but I didn't want to duplicate the code and will keep it easily editable/understandable (without base64 encoding and css/js in html).

I hope that there exist a solution with root modifications, proxy or similar.

Thank you again for your very constructive and helpful feedbacks!!